# npm - No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, npm

I encountered this after I reinstall my node from v12 to v8. I have checked the PATH System env and inserted the npm prefix..

But when I want to use firebase it appears - No such file or directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Uninstall nodejs from Uninstall Programme

Go to dir C:\Users{name}\AppData\Roaming\npm and delete the entire npm folder

then i install back nodejs from node installer from [nodejs website](https://nodejs.org/en/)

This way solved my problem. Hope it useful.